# Bootstrap drop down not working laravel twig

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twig, laravel-5

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
          crossorigin="anonymous">


<li class="navbar-right">
                <a  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> You
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><<a href="{{ url('/logout') }}">Logout</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
```

When I click on the drop down arrow it takes me to /# link but does not open the drop down menu. Can anyone help me with the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be a class .dropdown surrounding :

```
 <div class="dropdown">
      <a  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> You
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><<a href="{{ url('/logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
           </ul>
    </div>
```